# Open vSwitch installation fails - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:

Tags: kernel, ssh, virtualbox

I am installing `OVS v2.7.0` on `Ubuntu 14.04` with `kernel version 4.4.0-142-generic` (you can check the compatibility [here](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/releases/)) from source.

```
git clone https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs
cd ovs
git checkout v2.7.0
./boot.sh
./configure --with-linux=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build --prefix=/home/john14/ovs-build
make
make install
```

The commands above work fine and without error; however, an error pops up when I do

```
make modules_install
```

Here's the output:

```
cd datapath/linux && make modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux'
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-142-generic/build M=/home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic'
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/vport-geneve.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/vport-gre.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/vport-lisp.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/vport-stt.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux/vport-vxlan.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:169
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:172
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-142-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic'
depmod `sed -n 's/#define UTS_RELEASE "\([^"]*\)"/\1/p' /lib/modules/4.4.0-142-generic/build/include/generated/utsrelease.h`
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john14/Desktop/ovs/datapath/linux'
```

I have visited some links about the problem(see [here](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/139) , and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530623/openssl-error02001002system-libraryfopenno-such-file-or-directory-no-key-fou) ) but the solutions mentioned in those links either don't apply to my case(installing Open vSwitch) or simply don't work for me.

I appreciate your help if you can explain me some applicable method for installing modules. 
Thanks.

**P.S. :** I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on `virtualbox`. I have seen some links (like [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=76493)) about `dkms` problems that may cause my SSL Error but they didn't work, too.